# Partner Community Custom Button & Missing Activity

Tags: community, partner

[image]

I hope someone can help me with this as I have explored all options I am aware of.

I have a custom app for quoting that we have used with no issues for years. Recently, we started a partner community pilot with an active partner.  Since migrating to partner community we are no longer able to quote using the custom buttons. All works fine in lightning, and classic, but not partner community.

I spent time with the developer who assured me it works on other partner sites with no issues. I talk to Salesforce and they are still reviewing but I need to solve this as soon as possible as the partner is unable to quote.

I even set up a custom button to go to a public URL www.google.com.  Works no problem in Lightening and Classic but just clicks and goes nowhere in partner community.

------------------------------------ In addition

Thank you Jayant, here are some additional details.

Initially I had the partner running on a full Salesforce license. No problems at all. Due to cost and another 14 partners coming on board, we moved to partner licenses. It has not been a good experience. Once we migrated, none of the activity history came over. So for the entire month of October, we are missing a large chunk of data.  I managed a "band-aid" by making the tasks "public", so they would show, but when clicking on email, it goes to an unknown URL.  Currently this is unresolved with Salesforce Level 3.

For the button issue, it maybe connected to above, I just don't know. Our set-up is pretty simple with only one custom object.

Our primary domain for all communities is https://mytaqtik.force.com/
Our first partner community is https://mytaqtik.force.com/mmv/
Nothing really special other than it is using the partner central template.  I tried creating another test community with a different template, but using same profile and same thing.

I then tried, creating a default partner profile with a new community template to see if that might work same thing.
Our primary application is the ability to create packages which basically bundle products together, so it bypasses the standard (add opportunity) products. 
Not a complex setup, just the ability to manage opportunities, and quote is the primary requirements. 
The partner has profiles:  MMV Admin, MMV partner.  The Admin just has access to a couple more objects.

We do not have person accounts, although we do run Salesforce for B2B, and B2C, we just have 2 record types, client and business.  This is primarily to show different fields based on client, or business. 
I have read lots of documentation about inserting different scripts in the URL, but even a basic custom button called “test”, with a URL to google.com does not do anything in partner community.

This works great in classic, or lightning, but click no action in partner community.

In talking to the developer, he assures me that they have no problems with any functionality in other partner communities, so cannot give any more guidance. I did contact Salesforce to open a ticket, and they keep coming back to they do not support custom buttons.  YES, I get that, but the button should still work on an external website like www.google.com as it is independent from the application.

The button appears in Quote line Items (as per screen shot).  You can see what the buttons look like, as well as the test button I created which is just a URL that points to google.

MISSING ACTIVITY - PARTNER COMMUNITY

On another case, awaiting level 3 support, the activity history disappears in partner portal.  It can be viewed no problem in Classic and lightening and is gone from partner lightening.  A short term solution was to make all tasks public, but when clicking on the email is went to unknown URL.  I am not sure if the two are related in some way.

When a partner goes to view all activity, it searches this string: https://mytaqtik.force.com/mmv/s/runtime_sales_activities/activityViewAll.app?parentRecordId=0061Q00000l1RvnQAE

Then goes to unknown URL...:(

[image]

I am not sure if that helps but open to any help from any expert.

Comment: It will be difficult to say anything unless there's a minimum implementation details provided, as how is the community implemented (the template), where on the community is the button and how is the button implemented. If you can provide some details around implementation, then someone should be able to provide some direction.

Answer (score 0):

Example of original button code in Document Action:
/apex/rsdoc__GenerateDocument?id={!Lead.Id}&templateId=GDT-000004&attach=true&output=pdf&emailAction=autosend&emailTo={!Lead.Id}&emailTemplate=00X28000001SwGo

Example of how to change button code to work with Partner Community:
{!URLFOR($Site.Prefix + ‘/apex/rsdoc__GenerateDocument?id=’ + Lead.Id + ‘&templateId=GDT-000004&attach=true&output=pdf&emailAction=autosend&emailTo=’ + Lead.Id + ‘&emailTemplate=00X28000001SwGo’)}